# What gem qualities are there? What can be found and what has to be crafted?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 there seem to be a lot more gem quality levels than in Diablo 2.

How many quality levels are there?  Can all of the quality levels be found and if so is there a breakdown on how difficulty level affects it?

If they can't then how many lesser gems does it take to create the upper tier ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a total of **14** tiers of gems. **13** that you'll learn from the Jeweler, as well as the baseline *chipped* gems, which are not created. You'll need 3 gems of any level to create a gem of the next level. Higher level recipes will also require an additional ingredient, one or more **Pages of Jewelcrafting**, **Tomes of Jewelcrafting**, or **Tomes of Secrets**. However, all the way up to **Radiant Star** grade gems, which require 20 Tomes of Secrets, you will still only ever need 3 **Perfect Star** gems to create them.

You can see all of the relevant recipes over at [Blizzards item database.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/)