# Is Flawless square the highest quality gem type which drops?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How/where can I farm gems?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67317/how-where-can-i-farm-gems)

I've been farming inferno Act 1 and I'm not finding anything better than Flawless square gems. Is this the highest quality of gem which drops, or will I find higher quality ones in the later acts?

Comment: or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66863/what-gem-qualities-are-there-what-can-be-found-and-what-has-to-be-crafted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're in inferno, I assume you mean **flawless square.** Currently, flawless square is the highest that drops. Anything above that must be crafted.